# DatePickerFragment inside a Fragment not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to call a date time fragment from inside a fragment. I am passing EditText as an argument to DatePickerFragment so that once the date is set, it can update it in the UI. However, my app is getting aborted before it even starts

DateTimeFragment:

```
package com.example.makemyday;

import java.util.Calendar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class DateTimeFragment extends Fragment{

     private EditText editStartDate;
     private EditText editEndDate;
     @Override 
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       { 
         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_datetime, container, false);
         final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            ImageButton startDate=(ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.start_date_button);
            editStartDate = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.startDate);
            editStartDate.setText(Integer.toString(dd)+ "/" + Integer.toString(mm) +"/"+ Integer.toString(yy));

            ImageButton endDate=(ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.end_date_button);
            editEndDate = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.endDate);
            editEndDate.setText(Integer.toString(dd)+ "/" + Integer.toString(mm) +"/"+ Integer.toString(yy));


             startDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                           try
                            {
                               DialogFragment newFragment= (DialogFragment) new DatePickerFragment(editStartDate);
                               newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
                            }

                            catch(Exception e)
                            {

                                return ;
                            }
                    }
                });

             endDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                            try
                            {
                                 DialogFragment newFragment= (DialogFragment) new DatePickerFragment(editEndDate);
                                 newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                return ;
                            }
            }
        });

         return v;
      }


}
```

DatePickerFragment

```
package com.example.makemyday;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        /*public static interface OnCompleteListener {
            public abstract void onComplete(String date, int id);
        }

        private OnCompleteListener mListener;
        */
        private EditText edit_text;

        public DatePickerFragment(EditText edit_text) {
            this.edit_text=edit_text;
                    //buttonID=id;
        }
        /*// make sure the Activity implemented it
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            try {
                this.mListener = (OnCompleteListener)activity;
            }
            catch (final ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnCompleteListener");
            }
        }*/

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
             String date =Integer.toString(dd) + "/" + Integer.toString(mm)  + "/" + Integer.toString(yy);
             edit_text.setText(date);
              //this.mListener.onComplete(date,buttonID);

        }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
[2013-12-26 18:19:15 - MakeMyDay] ------------------------------
[2013-12-26 18:19:15 - MakeMyDay] Android Launch!
[2013-12-26 18:19:15 - MakeMyDay] adb is running normally.
[2013-12-26 18:19:15 - MakeMyDay] Performing com.example.makemyday.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-12-26 18:19:16 - MakeMyDay] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'HappifyV2'
[2013-12-26 18:19:16 - MakeMyDay] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'HappifyV2'
[2013-12-26 18:19:21 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Requested RAM size of 1907MB is too large for your environment, and is reduced to 1072MB.
[2013-12-26 18:19:21 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8
[2013-12-26 18:19:21 - Emulator] 
[2013-12-26 18:19:21 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2013-12-26 18:19:21 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Why is this code not working?

Comment: According to "WARNING: Requested RAM size of 1907MB is too large for your environment, and is reduced to 1072MB." You have to reduce your RAM size. It should be 1024MB or 1072MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is clearly because of the size of the RAM, and not because of the `DatePicker Fragment`. You need to reduce the size of the emulator's RAM down to 1GB (1024MB) and try running it again.